# Remove punctuation but not all of them

Tags: regex, hadoop, text, hive, punctuation

I am working on remove punctuation from a text variable that can be phase, etc.

Example: Hola, me llamo Juan! Hoy es día camión.

Code I am using is:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '[^0-9A-Za-z ]+', '')
```

This generally works well. Issue is that in some languages we have punctuation over some words. Example: día camión. When running the above code, the out for these words are "da" "camin". It removes the letter associate with the punctuation.

Is there a way to avoid this to happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- Use one of the many Unicode properties. For example, \p{L} matches any Unicode letter from any language - in this case, you could make it work with `[^0-9p\{L} ]+`. There are many different Unicode properties, and also differences between Regex flavors, so I'd recommend investigating [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for reference.
- If the solution above doesn't work for you, list specific Unicode codes that you want to match. For example, í can be matched with \u00ED, ó can be matched with \u00F3, so for this example [^\w\u00ED\u00F3 ]+ would do. There are many Unicode references out there, such as [this one](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/latin-1-supplement/) that you can use.

Besides that, \w has the same meaning as [0-9a-z_A-Z], and \W returns all characters not matched by \w, so you can replace that part of the expression, i.e. [\W ]+ instead of what you originally wrote. \W doesn't mitigate the Unicode issue, though - it's a matter of readability and simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Bane. Your explanation is a bit too technical to me I think Not getting it sorry... I have tried to replace  [0-9a-z_A-Z] by  [0-9a-z_A-Z] but has not done much...

Comment: <ul>Input:    Amazing Location + staff = AMAZING Location + staff = AMAZING Location + staff = AMAZING It&#39;s a hostel, you get what you paid for!

<ul>[^0-9A-Za-z ]+ solution:   Amazing Location staff AMAZING Location staff AMAZING Location staff AMAZING It39s a hostel you get what you paid for

<ul>[^0-9p\{L} ]+ solution:   L L L 39 p